# English word capture

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cpu-word

I have a big text file which contains many English words. However it contains German and French words as well. I need to capture all English words in it.

I reckon, firstly I read all file from the disk and convert it into an array, second I match the all words against unix English word dictionary like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3480849/665123), yet it is not a good solution because of the size of each file. If I do in that way, complexity will be high, and I don't want that.

Do you have any idea how I can do it with Ruby in a simple way?

Answer (score 1):

First thing you could do is to put the english dictionary to a [set](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) (instead of array). This way, the lookup is O(1) and overall complexity is O(N) instead of O(NxM).

Comment: out of curiosity what factors forced you to suggest `Set`?

Comment: O(1) lookup. Could be hash or set.

Comment: but I need to check all members of array one by one. Is there any gem like python enchant?

Comment: So, what's wrong with that? Don't you need to do the same with any other library?