# I need a way to define words in a rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

To clarify: I want to pass a word/phrase into a function and check whether it has a dictionary definition.

Any open source dictionary api/library that might be help? I was looking at wordnik but they seem to require an api key and for whatever reason, it hasn't been emailed to me.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473073/validate-words-against-an-english-dictionary-in-rails

Comment: a word list is ~3mb, would using a dictionary api read in a file of similar size?

Comment: also, i was hoping there was just a gem that could be used. like text.is_word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find your Wordnik API key on your user settings page: Wordnik.com/users/edit (it's all the way at the bottom)