# Ruby Hangman game, does not work when I enter the full word but only when I enter one letter

Tags: ruby, command-line

Run my code your ruby interpretor, to see my code. Afterwards, try to guess the full word. The program will tell you that your guess was correct but it doesn't end the game if you guess the entire word instead of each letter one by one.

I also want to add a Dictionary to my code to be able to play against the computer instead of with myself or a friend!

```
def clear_screen
  return system('cls') if Gem.win_platform?
  system('clear')
end

loop do

  incorrect_guesses = 0

  puts ''
  puts 'Welcome to Hangman, Win or lose your life!'
  puts ''
  puts 'Choose Category: It can be anything you desire!'
  player1_category = gets.chomp
  puts ''

  puts 'Player 1, Please enter your desired word'
  secret_word = gets.chomp.downcase
  clear_screen

  correct_guess = ['-'] * secret_word.length
  clear_screen
  puts "The category is: #{player1_category}"
  puts 'Player 2, Please enter your guess'

  loop do
    puts '_ ' * secret_word.length
    player2_guess = gets.chomp.downcase
    clear_screen


if secret_word.include? player2_guess
    secret_word.each_char.with_index do |letter, i|
    next unless letter == player2_guess
    correct_guess[i] = letter
  end
  puts "The category is: #{player1_category}"
  puts ''
  print 'Guess the word: '
  print correct_guess.join('')
  puts ''
  puts 'Correct. Keep trying!!'
  puts ''
else
  puts "The category is: #{player1_category}"
  puts ''
  print 'Guess the word: '
  print correct_guess.join('')
  puts ''
  puts "The word doesn't contain that letter '#{player2_guess.upcase}'"
  puts ''
  incorrect_guesses += 1
end
puts "Incorrect Guesses: #{incorrect_guesses}"
puts ''

if incorrect_guesses == 6
  puts ''
  puts '|---+---+- '
  puts  '|   |'
  puts  '|   0'
  puts  '|   |\\'
  puts  '|   /\\'
  puts  '-+----------'
  puts "The Secret Word is '#{secret_word.capitalize!}'"
  puts ''
  break
end

next unless secret_word == correct_guess.join('')
puts ''
puts '   (@)'
puts '  ^\\|'
puts '    |/^'
puts '____|_____'
puts ''
puts 'You Win!'
puts ''
puts "You correctly guessed the word '#{secret_word.capitalize!}'"
break
end
end
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. A couple things - if you're getting an error, please include the full stack trace. Also please emphasize the core of your problem and try not to include too much tangential information. Writing Ruby, you can go a long way with a debugger like `pry`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to work with the following change to the next unless test:

```
  if secret_word.include? player2_guess
    secret_word.each_char.with_index do |letter, i|
      next unless player2_guess.include?  letter
      correct_guess[i] = letter
    end
```

You were comparing the entire entry to a single character. 't' != 'test'

As for a dictionary, the answer in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473073/validate-words-against-an-english-dictionary-in-rails) should help

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not super clear, but here are a few comments / answers:

1. Guessing the whole word: You could wrap your current `if secret_word.include? player2_guess` in another if that tests the length of the input. (This assumes all words are greater than 1 letter). The if statement should test if the `user_input.length > 1`. If so, evaluate whether the guess is the correct word, etc.
2. Adding a dictionary: Easiest was would be to hardcode an array of possible word values. If you want them to correspond to a category, you could make a hash like this `{'category_1' => [word, word, word], 'category_2' => [word, word, word]}`. Then you could pick a random value from the hash (category) and then a random value from the corresponding array.