# Finding dictionary words within a source text, using Ruby

Tags: ruby, dictionary

Using Ruby, I need to output a list of words, found in a dictionary, that can be formed by eliminating letters from a source text.

E.g., if I input the source text "crazed" I want to get not only words like "craze" and "razed", whose letters are in the same order AND whose letters are adjacent to each other within the source text, but ALSO words like "rad" and "red", because those words exist and can be found by eliminating select letters from "crazed" AND the output words retain letter order. BUT, words like "dare" or "race" should not be in the output list, because the letter order of the letters in "dare" or "race" are not the same as those letters found in "crazed". (If "raed" or "crae" were words in the dictionary, they WOULD be part of the output.)

My thought was to go through the source text in a binary manner

```
(for "crazed", we'd get: 
000001 = "d"; 
000010 = "e"; 
000011 = "ed"; 
000100 = "z"; 
000101 = "zd"; 
000111 = "zed"; 
001000 = "a"; 
001001 = "ad"; etc.)
```

and compare each result with words in a dictionary, though I don't know how to code that, nor whether that is most efficient. This is where I would greatly benefit from your help.

Also, the length of the source text would be variable; it wouldn't necessarily be six letters long (like "crazed"). Inputs would potentially be much larger (20-30 characters, possibly more).

I've searched here and found questions about anagrams and about words that can be in any letter order, but not specifically what i'm looking for. Is this even possible in Ruby? Thank you.

Comment: The first question is whose dictionary are you using? I don't see why you would want to convert these to binary unless you have a handy Binary to English dictionary
For a ruby String `word` you can use `word.each_char.to_a` gets you the 'Array' of characters..

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473073/validate-words-against-an-english-dictionary-in-rails

Comment: @whodini9, `word.chars` is enough.

Comment: I just noticed that that I said I had used `bsearch` in my answer, but it was nowhere to be found in my code. I fixed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's read the words of a dictionary into an array, after chomping, downcasing and removing duplicates (if, for example, the dictionary contains both `"A"` and `"a"`, as does the dictionary on my Mac that I've used below).

```
DICTIONARY = File.readlines("/usr/share/dict/words").map { |w| w.chomp.downcase }.uniq
  #=> ["a", "aa", "aal", "aalii",..., "zyzomys", "zyzzogeton"]  
DICTIONARY.size
  #=> 234371
```

The following method generates all combinations of one or more characters of a given word, respecting order, and for each, joins the characters to form a string, checks to see if the string is in the dictionary, and if it is, saves the string to an array.

To check if a string matches a word in the dictionary I perform a binary search, using the method [Array#bsearch](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch). This makes use of the fact that the dictionary is already sorted in alphabetical order.

```
def subwords(word)
  arr = word.chars
  (1..word.size).each.with_object([]) do |n,a|
    arr.combination(n).each do |comb|
      w = comb.join
      a << w if DICTIONARY.bsearch { |dw| w <=> dw }
    end
  end
end

subwords "crazed"
  # => ["c", "r", "a", "z", "e", "d",
  #     "ca", "ce", "ra", "re", "ae", "ad", "ed",
  #     "cad", "rad", "red", "zed",
  #     "raze", "craze", "crazed"]
```

Yes, that particular dictionary contains all those strings (such as `"z"`) that don't appear to be English words.

Another example.

```
subwords "importance"
  #=> ["i", "m", "p", "o", "r", "t", "a", "n", "c", "e",
  #    "io", "it", "in", "ie", "mo", "mr", "ma", "me", "po", "pa", "or",
  #      "on", "oe", "ra", "re", "ta", "te", "an", "ae", "ne", "ce",
  #    "imp", "ima", "ion", "ira", "ire", "ita", "ian", "ice", "mor", "mot",
  #      "mon", "moe", "man", "mac", "mae", "pot", "poa", "pon", "poe", "pan", 
  #      "pac", "ort", "ora", "orc", "ore", "one", "ran", "tan", "tae", "ace",
  #    "iota", "ione", "iran", "mort", "mora", "morn", "more", "mote",
  #      "moan", "mone", "mane", "mace", "port", "pore", "pote", "pone",
  #      "pane", "pace", "once", "rane", "race", "tane",
  #    "impot", "moran", "morne", "porta", "ponce", "rance",
  #    "import", "impone", "impane", "prance",
  #    "portance",
  #    "importance"]
```

Answer (score 0):

An extensive solution set that comprises words that can be obtained from using letters in any order is below. The catch with using combination to find possible subwords is that the permutations of the combinations are missed. eg: drawing from 'importance', the combination of 'mpa' will arise at some point. since this isn't a dictionary word, it'll be skipped. thereby costing us, the permutation 'map'-- dictionary subword of 'importance'. below is an extensive solution that finds more possible dictionary words. I agree that my method can be optimized for speed.

```
#steps
#split string at ''
#find combinations for n=2 all the way to n=word.size
#for each combination
#find the permutations of all the arrangements
#then
#join the array
#check to see if word is in dictionary
#and it's not already collected
#if it is, add to collecting array

require 'set'
Dictionary=File.readlines('dictionary.txt').map(&:chomp).to_set
Dictionary.size #39501

def subwords(word)
    #split string at ''
  arr=word.split('')

  #excluding single letter words
  #you can change 2 to 1 in line below to select for single letter words too
  (2..word.size).each_with_object([]) do |n,a|

    #find combinations for n=2 all the way to n=word.size
    arr.combination(n).each do |comb|

        #for each combination
        #find the permutations of all the arrangements
      comb.permutation(n).each do |perm|
        
        #join the array
        w=perm.join

        #check to see if word is in dictionary and it's not already collected
        if Dictionary.include?(w) && !a.include?(w)

            #if it is, add to collecting array
          a<<w
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

p subwords('crazed')
#["car", "arc", "rec", "ace", "cad", "are", "era", "ear", "rad", "red", "adz", "zed", "czar", "care", "race", "acre", "card", "dace", "raze", "read", "dare", "dear", "adze", "daze", "craze", "cadre", "cedar", "crazed"]
p subwords('battle')
#["bat", "tab", "alb", "lab", "bet", "tat", "ate", "tea", "eat", "eta", "ale", "lea", "let", "bate", "beat", "beta", "abet", "bale", "able", "belt", "teat", "tale", "teal", "late", "bleat", "table", "latte", "battle", "tablet"]
```